# Perl Hook::LexWrap Unable to access return value in post wrapper method

Tags: perl, rt

We are customising the Request Tracker (RT) ticketing tool. We want to add certain extra filters to the values returned from `SimpleSearch` subroutine in `RT::Users`.

Following Hook::Lexwrap code we have written to access the return value and the arguments from the above subroutine.

*Users_Local.pm*

```
package RT::Users;
use strict;
use Hook::LexWrap;
wrap 'SimpleSearch' =>
    post=> sub {
        RT::Logger->info("accessing return value here $_[-1]");
        RT::Logger->info("I got the arguments in post: [@_]");
    },
;
1;
```

Following is the output:

**accessing return value here**  (/opt/requestTracker/sbin/../local/lib/RT/Users_Local.pm:6)

I am not able to understand why an empty value exists in $_[-1].

Following is the text quoted from http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Hook-LexWrap-0.25/lib/Hook/LexWrap.pm

"*In a post-wrapper, $_[-1] contains the return value
produced by the wrapped subroutine. In a scalar return
context, this value is the scalar return value. In an
list return context, this value is a reference to the
array of return values. $_[-1] may be assigned to in a
post-wrapper, and this changes the return value accordingly*."

How can I access the return value from the original subroutine? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the example code from Hook::LexWrap perldoc and found that $_[-1] is undefined only when wrapped subroutine is called in a void context.
So, make sure that you assign return value from your subroutine to some variable.

Comment: Thanks. Assigning the value returned from the called subroutine to a variable in the caller subroutine resolved it.